# Why does reading into a string buffer with scanf work both with and without the ampersand (&)?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm a little bit confused about something. I was under the impression that the correct way of reading a C string with `scanf()` went along the lines of

(never mind the possible buffer overflow, it's just a simple example)

```
char string[256];
scanf( "%s" , string );
```

However, the following seems to work too,

```
scanf( "%s" , &string );
```

Is this just my compiler (gcc), pure luck, or something else?

Comment: In the second case, there's actually no possible buffer overflow, as you aren't using that buffer at all. Either that, or you could say that any string larger than 3 characters will overflow your "buffer".

Comment: I was referring to the first example. Also, others have already pointed out what's going on here.

Comment: Yup. Tried it out, and Gareth is right. Weird.

Comment: Since this question is returned by searches for "how to read a string with scanf", it might be appropriate to point out that this question is about ways to pass the pointer to the buffer to `scanf`, and both the question and the accepted answer focus on that, and omit the _critically important_ restrictions for maximum input length that should be used in real code (but are besides the point for this question).

Answer (score 164, accepted):

An array "decays" into a pointer to its first element, so `scanf("%s", string)` is equivalent to `scanf("%s", &string[0])`. On the other hand, `scanf("%s", &string)` passes a pointer-to-`char[256]`, but it points to the same place.

Then `scanf`, when processing the tail of its argument list, will try to pull out a `char *`. That's the Right Thing when you've passed in `string` or `&string[0]`, but when you've passed in `&string` you're depending on something that the language standard doesn't guarantee, namely that the pointers `&string` and `&string[0]` -- pointers to objects of different types and sizes that start at the same place -- are represented the same way.

I don't believe I've ever encountered a system on which that doesn't work, and in practice you're probably safe. None the less, it's wrong, and it could fail on some platforms. (Hypothetical example: a "debugging" implementation that includes type information with every pointer. I *think* the C implementation on the Symbolics "Lisp Machines" did something like this.)

Answer (score -12):

I think that this below is accurate and it may help. 
Feel free to correct it if you find any errors. I'm new at C.

```
char str[]
```

1. array of values of type char, with its own address in memory
2. array of values of type char, with its own address in memory
   as many consecutive addresses as elements in the array
3. including termination null character `'\0'` `&str`, `&str[0]` and `str`, all three represent the same location in memory which is address of the first element of the array `str`

   char *strPtr = &str[0]; //declaration and initialization

alternatively, you can split this in two:

```
char *strPtr; strPtr = &str[0];
```

4. `strPtr` is a pointer to a `char`
5. `strPtr` points at array `str`
6. `strPtr` is a variable with its own address in memory
7. `strPtr` is a variable that stores value of address `&str[0]`
8. `strPtr` own address in memory is different from the memory address that it stores (address of array in memory a.k.a &str[0])
9. `&strPtr` represents the address of strPtr  itself

I think that you could declare a pointer to a pointer as:

```
char **vPtr = &strPtr;
```

declares and initializes with address of strPtr pointer

Alternatively you could split in two:

```
char **vPtr;
*vPtr = &strPtr
```

10. `*vPtr` points at strPtr pointer
11. `*vPtr` is a variable with its own address in memory
12. `*vPtr` is a variable that stores value of address &strPtr
13. final comment:  you can not do `str++`, `str` address is a `const`,  but
    you can do `strPtr++`