# Problems with scanf on strings with spaces

Tags: c, scanf

I have this simple code in C to scan and print a string with a whitespace:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
   char myName[50];
   printf("Enter your name: ");
   scanf("%[^\n]s", &myName);
   printf("Your name is: %s", myName);
   return 0;
}
```

The compiler (gcc, part of the command line tools that come with Xcode on my mac) is returning this error:

```
name.c: In function ‘main’:
name.c:7: warning: format ‘%[^
’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[50]’
name.c:7: warning: format ‘%[^
’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[50]’
```

What's the problem here?

NOTE: I am required to use scanf. No fgets for me :(

Comment: you might need to use '&myName[0]'. But I could be wrong

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading a string with scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf)

Comment: @Martin it's legal C, because the address of the array and the address of its first element is the same.

Comment: @Mauren. That is true, but &myName != &myName[0]

Answer (score 4):

You should pass to `scanf` argument of type `char*` (format `%[^\n]s` expects so), but in your code:

```
char myName[50];
scanf("%[^\n]s", &myName);
```

you pass an address of `myName` array (i.e. `char (*)[50]`). You should change it either to:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", myName);
```

or:

```
scanf("%[^\n]", &myName[0]);
```

Comment: Recommend dropping the `s` in `"%[^\n]s"` as it is not needed.  Leaving it there implies it is somehow useful.

Comment: OP's question is "Problems with scanf on strings with _spaces_".  Using the `%[]` specifier is used to read strings with _spaces_.  I fully agree that the `&` issue is central to the OP's problem.  But incorrect usage of the format specifier (unneeded `s`) certainly is a related problem given the OP's title.

Answer (score 2):

Couple issues

1. Wrong `scanf()` format `s`.  The `s` is *not* part of the format specifier.  The `%[]` format specifier ends with the `]`.
2. Wrong `scanf()` parameter `&myName`.  Rather than passing the address of `&myName`, which is type `char (*)[50]` , simply use `myName`.  This will pass the address of the first element of `myName` which is a `char *`, the expected matching type for `%[]`.

Use

```
scanf("%[^\n]", myName);
```

Further recommend to consume leading white space and limit text read.  The `49` limits the input to 49 characters, leaving 1 more byte for the terminating `\0`.

```
scanf(" %49[^\n]", myName);
```

Comment: I get same results with either `"%49[^\n]s"` or `"%[^\n]s"`.  What exactly is this supposed to do?

Comment: @ryyker The `49` limits the amount of text read to 49 `char`.  Had you type in a long name, `myName` would overfill thus invoking undefined behavior.  BTW, you do not need the `s`.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the problem here?

Well, here it is:

```
format expects type ‘char *’, but argument has type ‘char (*)[50]’
```

A pointer to an array is not the same as a pointer to the first element of an array. You should get rid of that `&` operator.

Answer (score 1):

In C, `myName` (when passed to a function) decays to a pointer to the first element of array (`myname`) of characters. `&myName` is a pointer to the array `myname`. `&myName[0]` would be a pointer to the first character, which is correct, but looks like you tried stuff at random until you chanced on something that worked.

Comment: No, `myName` is an array, which decays into a pointer. `&myName` is not a pointer to pointer, it's a pointer to an array.

Comment: Same difference. He needs to delete the ampersand.

Comment: If he types myName there, he's passing the pointer. Yes, technically, I should use the word "decay". Or "treated as", or something. OK. Next time I will (if I remember, which at this late stage of my career, I promise you I won't). But it'll compile and work and his understanding will be correct for all practical purposes if he thinks of myName as a pointer when he passes it, because a pointer will be what he is passing when he does that. "Incorrect", whatever.

Comment: Well, you definitely can. Write "array" instead of "pointer" and it will be correct.

Comment: Calling `myName` a pointer is problematic when explaining `sizeof`.  Many posts reflect that challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your are passing the address to the pointer of the start of the string, rather than the pointer to the string. Simply, remove the `&`.

```
   scanf("%[^\n]", myName);
```

Comment: Also the `s` does not make sense here. `%[^\n]` already asks for all characters but a new-line.