# how to use fscanf to read from ( to )?

Tags: c

How can you use scanf in c to read string between brackets? for example how can I get "myString" if text in a file is "text a 123 (myString) text"?

Comment: This question should be asked in a programming site like stackoverflow or [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about programming in C (and really has nothing to do with Unix or Linux). Please consider [so].

Comment: Instead of trying to squeeze `scanf()` to the limit of what it can do, and risk creating a bug, consider using a regexp library.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%[]` as a poor man's regexp :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   const char data[] = "text a 123 (myString) text";
   char str[20];
   int cr = sscanf( data, "%*[^(](%[^)])", str ); /* skip until '(' and read up to ')' */
   if (cr == 1) {
        printf(">%s<\n", str);
   }
   else {
       printf("NOT FOUND\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

above program correctly outputs :

```
>myString<
```

Comment: Likely good enough for OP, but this does not insure a final `')'` existed nor the subsequent "text".

Answer (score 0):

Just to read your line you can have something like

```
char a[50];
fscanf(stdin,"%*s %*s %*d (%[^)]) %*s",a);
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. `a` is a char array. The `fscanf()` call should take `a` as argument, not `&a`.

Comment: Quoting from [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5407121/3488231), "it's wrong, and it could fail on some platforms". They are pointers to different types. If you compile with gcc, this shows up: `warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[50]’ [-Wformat=]`

Comment: @ace Very hard why this might fail and as the answer says who knows on which platform this fails

Comment: I suspect there is an error: `s` after `[` is not a format specifier, but expected next character.

Comment: @kestasx Sorry I didn't get ?

Comment: @Gopi Lose the `s` after the `]`.

Comment: @Gopi, in Your format string `...(%[^)]s...` character `s` is not a format specifier for string. Format string as You wrote matches string until `)`, then instead of consuming this `)` it expects `s`, and only after it `)`.

Answer (score 0):

Full example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
   const char data[] = "text a 123 (myString) text";
   char str[20];
   sscanf( data, "%*s %*c %*d (%[^)]", str );
   puts( str );
   return 0;
}
```

Updated:

You can replace sscanf line with the following (ignore avrytihing until `(` and then read until `)`:

```
sscanf( data, "%*[^(](%[^)]", str );
```

Note: I'm not sure how portable such programming practice is, but it works at least on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

Example  :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
        char mystring[1025];
        FILE * fp = NULL;
        fp= fopen("dd.txt","r");
        if(!fp){

        }else{
                fscanf(fp, "%*s %*c %*d (%[^)] %*s",mystring);
                printf("%s\n",mystring);
        }

        fclose(fp);

}
```