# Creating an array of struct (c)

Tags: c

i've created a struct "Employee"

```
#define MAX_SIZE 20

typedef struct Employee{
    char name[MAX_SIZE];
    int s;
    int e;
} employee_s;
```

and i need to create an array of 2 employees and ask the user to initialize them, nothing i try seem to work,

```
void main()
{
    int i, s, e;
    char name[10];
    Employee* e[3];

    *e = (Employee*)malloc(sizeof(Employee)*ARR_SIZE);

    for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        fflush(stdin);
        puts("Please enter Employee's name:");
        scanf("%c",&name);
        *e[i]->name = name;

        puts("Please enter Employee's salary:");
        scanf("%d",&s);
       *e[i]->s= s;

        puts("Please enter Employee's experience:");
        scanf("%d",&e);
       *e[i]->e=e;

    }
}
```

p.s: i dont have to use dynamic allocation, 
what do i do wrong?

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several errors here:

- `Employee` is not a valid type.  `struct Employee` is, and so is `employee_s`.
- `e` is defined in multiple places
- When reading in `name`, use `%s` (for a string), not `%c` (for a char)
- Your employee array is defined as an array of pointers.  That's probably not what you want.  You just need an array.  No call to `malloc` either.
- Never `fflush(stdin)`.  It's undefined behavior.
- In your `scanf` calls, put a space as the first character in the string.  That will allow any newlines to be passed over.

The result:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    employee_s e[3];

    for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        puts("Please enter Employee's name:");
        scanf(" %s",&e[i].name);

        puts("Please enter Employee's salary:");
        scanf(" %d",&e[i].s);

        puts("Please enter Employee's experience:");
        scanf(" %d",&e[i].e);
    }

    for(i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("emp %d: name=%s, sal=%d, exp=%d\n", i, e[i].name, e[i].s, e[i].e);
    }
}
```

Comment: `&e[i].name` should be `e[i].name`. And those spaces before the format specifier are unnecessary.

Comment: @CoolGuy Although generally we don't use `&` while reading in character array but I think there is not any problem in using `&e[i].name` instead of `e[i].name`. Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf)

Comment: thank you very much!
one thing i did not understand is why not using fflush(stdin), if i want to recive string it will not take the garbage values in the buffer otherwise?

Comment: @HardikModha Hmm. But as that answer you linked says, it is wrong and the standard doesn't say anything about it. Also, you get a warning. So it is better to avoid it.

Comment: @user3142625 What? Could you clarify? Your comment seems to be unclear for me.

Comment: @CoolGuy Yes..We should avoid it. I was just making clear that we can use `&` also. (see my answer I haven't used it! ;) )

Comment: hmm dbush wrote "Never fflush(stdin). It's undefined behavior."
i do not understand why :(

Comment: @user3142625 The leading space in each `scanf` format string matches zero or more whitespace characters, so any newlines or spaces are skipped over.  Also, from the `fflush` manpage: "The function fflush()  forces a write of all user-space buffered data for the given *output or update stream* via the stream’s underlying write function."  `stdin` is not an output or update stream.

Answer (score 2):

You've got your declaration backward.  This:

```
typedef struct Employee{
    char name[MAX_SIZE];
    int s;
    int e;
} employee_s;
```

declares a type named `employee_s` to be equivalent to `struct Employee`, and furthermore declares `struct Employee`.  You appear to want this, instead:

```
typedef struct employee_s {
    char name[MAX_SIZE];
    int s;
    int e;
} Employee;
```

In this case you can omit `employee_s` from that if you wish; perhaps that would be less confusing.

Moreover, you are going about your allocation in a very strange way, especially since you don't require dynamic allocation.  Why not just do this:

```
Employee e[3];
```

? Then you can (and should) skip `malloc()` altogether.  You will then refer to the members of the array elements via the form `e[0].name`, etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily without dynamic memory allocation as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 20
typedef struct Employee{
    char name[MAX_SIZE];
    int s;
    int e;
} employee_alias;
int main(void) {
    int i;
    employee_alias e[3];
    for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        puts("Please enter Employee's name:");
        scanf("%s",e[i].name);
        puts("Please enter Employee's salary:");
        scanf("%d",&e[i].s);
        puts("Please enter Employee's experience:");
        scanf("%d",&e[i].e);

        printf("Entered Data\n");
        printf("Name : %s\n",e[i].name);
        printf("Salary : %d\n",e[i].s);
        printf("Experience : %d\n",e[i].e);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char name[10];` is unused. So, Remove it