# How to exit a while loop when a user inputs the letter "q" - C Programming

Tags: c, while-loop

Working on this assignment. Not sure how to get out of the while loop and I can't use anything more advanced than a while loop. I tried casting the int to a char but that didn't work. Below is my code. Any help would be appreciated.

```
/* This program has the user input a number. This number is then printed out in degrees F, C and K*/

#include <stdio.h>

#define KEL 273.16
#define CEL1 32
#define CEL2 0.5555

void temperatures(double temp);


int main(void)
{
    double tempF; // Temperature the user inputs

    char userinput; // Quit character the user inputs

    userinput = 'a';

    tempF = 0;

    printf("Enter a temperature in degrees Farenheit or enter q to quit:\n");
    scanf_s("%lf", &tempF);
    //scanf_s("%c", &userinput);

    while ((char)tempF  != 'q')
    {
        temperatures(tempF);
        printf("Enter a temperature in degrees Farenheit or enter q to quit:\n");
        scanf_s("%lf", &tempF);
        //scanf_s("%c", &userinput);

    }

    printf("Goodbye!\n");


    return 0;
}

void temperatures(double temp)
{
    double celsius;
    double kelvins;

    celsius = (temp - CEL1) * CEL2;
    kelvins = celsius + KEL;

    printf("%lf F is %lf degrees C or %lf degrees K.\n", temp, celsius, kelvins);


}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to change your strategy.

1. Read a line of text.
2. If the first letter of the line is `q`, then exit.
3. Otherwise, try to read the number from the line using `sscanf`.

Here's a version of `main` that does that.

```
int main(void)
{
   double tempF; // Temperature the user inputs
   char line[200];

   while ( 1 )
   {
      printf("Enter a temperature in degrees Fahrenheit or enter q to quit:\n");

      // Read a line of text.
      if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) == NULL )
      {
         break;
      }

      if ( line[0] == 'q' )
      {
         break;
      }

      if ( sscanf(line, "%lf", &tempF) == 1 )
      {
         // Got the temperature
         // Use it.
      }
      else
      {
         // The line does not have a number
         // Deal with the error.
      }
   }

   printf("Goodbye!\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should read the input as string ([scanning a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf)) and convert it ([atof](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/)), than use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/?kw=strcmp) to compare the input string with your exit command.
You can also use [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/?kw=isdigit) to check your input (not try to convert anything that is not a number)

Answer (score 0):

You can read characters with

```
char c;
while (c != 'q') {
    scanf("%c", &c);
    //parse command
}
```