# Segmentation fault core (dumped)

Tags: c

This is my code on getting details of a student.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct det{
    char fname[25], lname[25], shift[10], sec[2];
    int roll, clss, id;
};

int details();

int main(){
    details();

    getchar();
    getchar();

    return 0;
}

int details(){
    char rl;
    FILE *fp;
    struct det n;

    printf ("\n Enter Student Informations Below : \n\n");

    printf (" First Name : ");
    scanf ("%s",&n.fname);

    printf (" Last Name : ");
    scanf ("%s",&n.lname);

    printf (" Roll : ");
    scanf ("%d",&n.roll);

    rl = (char) n.roll + ".txt";

    fp = fopen(rl, "w");

    printf (" ID : ");
    scanf ("%d",&n.id);

    printf (" Class : ");
    scanf ("%d",&n.clss);

    printf (" Shift : ");
    scanf ("%s",&n.shift);

    printf (" Section : ");
    scanf ("%s",&n.sec);

    // Works fine till here. Shows in console that segmentation fault, core dumped.

    fprintf (fp, "\n Name : %s %s\n", n.fname, n.lname);
    fprintf (fp, " Class : %d\n Roll : %d\n ID : %d\n", n.clss, n.roll, n.id);
    fprintf (fp, " Section : %s\n Shift : %s\n", n.sec, n.shift);

    fclose(fp);

    printf ("\n\n Details Stored.\n\n Press Enter To Exit...");

    return 0;
}
```

Works fine till the marked line. But then i get this message on console 'Segmentation fault. Core(Dumped). Can someone please tell me what's wrong in the code and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you run your code through a debugger? Or with something like valgrind?

Comment: Have you looked at any compiler warnings? Make sure to turn them all on, and don't ignore them if you're not sure about them.

Comment: At least format your code correctly. Even better, make some effort to try and understand where your program is going wrong (by using a debugger or inserting debugging statements), and include results of such investigation in the question.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem #1

```
char fname[25];
scanf ("%s",&n.fname);
```

As explained [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf), this might seem to work, but it is wrong. Use `scanf("%s", fname);`

## Problem #2

```
rl = (char) n.roll + ".txt";
```

This statement does not concatenate strings, as you probably meant to do; the binary `+` operator in C does not work like that. What is happening here:

- `".txt"` is an expression of type "pointer to `char`", that points to the first element of the sequence ([C11 6.3.2.1p3](http://mfukar.github.io/resources/n1570.html#6.5.6))
- `(char) n.roll` casts an `int` to a narrower **integer** type, `char`, and thus discards some information. If you need a `char`, use a `char`, otherwise document its purpose
- `(char) n.roll` is of integer type, therefore if its value N is in the range [0, 4], the result is of type "pointer to `char`" and points to the N-th element of the array object, otherwise the behaviour is undefined
  ([C11 6.5.6p8](http://mfukar.github.io/resources/n1570.html#6.5.6))
- the result is assigned to `rl`, which is of type `char`, which means you are trying to assign a pointer to an integer (and should be seeing a warning that says exactly that)

If you wanted to safely create a character string, which contains a string of the form "NNN.txt", you use string formatting functions like `snprintf`:

```
char buffer[MAXIMUM_FILENAME_SIZE];
snprintf (buffer, sizeof buffer, "%d.txt", n.roll);
```

Then check for errors and handle them appropriately.