# Why I can not use the inputted value from one-dimensional array, in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I understand that: I can use a **two-dimensional** array for storaging many strings. But, I would like to solve this problem with **one-dimensional**; so, please **do not** advise me to use **two-dimensional** array for solving.

---

I have a small **one-dimensional** array, which is used for storaging many strings. Here is all of source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    #define MAX 10

    int N = 3;

    char * str[MAX];

    printf("Input a string in each line:\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("str[%d] = ", i);
         gets(str[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n---\n\nExport the list of strings:\n\n");

    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        printf("str[%d] = ", j);
        printf("%s\n", str[j]);
    }

}
```

When I compile it, the compiler **does not** return any error or warning. But, after I inputted the data, there is an error message from Windows:

> A problem caused the program to stop working correctly

Then, my program is broken.

Comment: `&str[i]` is incorrect and you don't allocate any memory for the strings either.

Comment: Related: [Reading a string with scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf)

Comment: [simple code](http://ideone.com/dmsf4U)

Comment: `char str[MAX];` is 1D-Array. Why do you think it is different?

Comment: Have you ever heard about Array of Pointers, or moreover about Pointers?

Answer (score 3):

In this array: `char * str[MAX]`

None of the entries is initialized to point to a valid (properly allocated) memory block.

And so you should not `scanf("%s", &str[i])` until you have initialized entry #`i`.

Answer (score 1):

```
char * str[MAX];
```

`str` is an array of pointers. You should allocate memory to pointers before writing anything to it.

```
str[i] = malloc(20);/* Showing an example of using malloc() . How much memory should be allocated is left to you */
```

Using a `scanf()` to scan a string is not a good idea I would rather prefer `fgets()`

Comment: What's wrong with scanf? It is almost always wrong used.