# Why does printf prints only first character of a character array whose input was read through scanf

Tags: c

This code is supposed to read input string through scanf and store the input string in an array declared here as msg[] and then print those input string, but when I run the code all it prints is just the first character of the string. It looks really simple but I am not able to solve it.

If I type `i do`, it only reports `i`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char msg[5]; 
    printf("enter the message: ");
    scanf("%s",msg);           
    printf("entered msg is: %s", msg); 
}
```

Comment: your array can store up to `4 chars` plus a `null terminator`.......

Comment: shouldnt it print atleast upto 4th character?

Comment: Not _at least_, but *up to* 4 chars. BTW what is the user input?

Comment: @LPs not if it invoked UB before, while scanning

Comment: Shouldn't scanf be: scanf("%s", &msg); ?

Comment: I assume the input is _"more than the array can handle"_ sort?

Comment: @BioGenX no, and ready about array decay.

Comment: sorry atmost 4 characters. any input that i give it prints only first chracter for eg if i give input "i do" it prints only 'i' and yea even when i give input more than the specified size of array for eg " i love the foods that i cook" even then it prints only 'i'

Comment: If you input more that 4 chars the behavior is undefined due to buffer overflow.

Comment: Step 1: `scanf("%s",msg);` --> `scanf("%4s",msg);`  (edit in a `4`)

Comment: [Take a look at your code working](http://ideone.com/HW4TQg)

Comment: same output with scanf("%4s",msg);

Comment: Try adding `\n` to the end of your second `printf` string.

Comment: Add a `'\n'` to both `printf()`

Comment: hey thanks everyone my issue is resolved . it was printing only first charcater because i gave space after the first charcter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a string with scanf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is hidden in the comments. The OP states `if i give input "i do" it prints only 'i'` .

scanf only reads until the first whitespace (which is the `i` in `i do`).

If you input 4 characters, 4 characters are printed.

Please edit your question to include this information for future searchers.

Comment: "scanf only reads until the first whitespace" --> It depends on the format.  `"%s"` first reads and discards leading white-space - it does not stop.  Then it reads non-whitespace characters until reaching a whitespace.

Comment: @chux - correct, I answered the question asked by the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` conversion specifier tells `scanf` to skip over any leading whitespace, then read up to (but not including) the next whitespace character.  So when you enter `"i do"`, the `%s` conversion specifier only reads `"i"`.

If you want to read strings *with* whitespace, you'll have to use a different method.  You can use the `%[` conversion specifier like so:

```
scanf( "%[^\n]", msg );
```

which will read everything (including leading whitespace characters) until it sees the `'\n'` newline character and stores it to `msg`.  Unfortunately, this (and the `%s` specifier above) leave you open to buffer overflow - if your user enters a string longer than `msg` is sized to hold, `scanf` will happily write those extra characters to the memory following the `msg` buffer, leading to all kinds of mayhem.  To prevent that, you'd use a field width in the conversion spec, like so:

```
scanf( "%4[^\n]", msg );
```

This tells `scanf` to read no more than 4 characters into `msg`.  Unfortunately, that width has to be hardcoded - you can't pass it as an argument the way you can with `printf`.

IMO, a better way to go would be to use `fgets`:

```
fgets( msg, sizeof msg, stdin );
```