# Program in C not calculating % and break/exit on specific input

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a small program, where user enters a list of numbers and at the end it shows how much in % of the numbers are odd or even.

If the user enters no value (just presses enter) it stops request a number and shows the calculation, but if the user enters `exit` it exits. Additionally I want to check if the entered number is a whole number.

Here what I got so far:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int input, all [100], even[100], odd[100], even_counter, even_print, odd_counter, odd_print, total_counter, total_print, even_p, odd_p;
    char cinput;
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("Enter a number: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &cinput) != 1) break;
        input=(int)(cinput-0);
        all[total_counter]=input; //Insert number in all numbers array

        if (input % 2 == 0)
        {
            even[even_counter]=input; //Insert number in even numbers array
            even_counter++;
            total_counter++;
        }
        if (input % 2 != 0)
        {
            odd[odd_counter]=input; //Insert number in odd numbers array
            odd_counter++;
            total_counter++;
        }
    }

    printf("\n You entered the following numbers: ");
    for (total_print=0; total_print<total_counter; total_print++)
    {
        printf("%d ", all[total_print]); //Show all entered numbers
    }
    printf("\n Even numbers are: ");
    for (even_print=0; even_print<even_counter; even_print++)
    {
        printf("%d ", even[even_print]); //Show even numbers only
    }
    printf("\n Odd numbers are: ");
    for (odd_print=0; odd_print<odd_counter; odd_print++)
    {
        printf("%d ", odd[odd_print]); //show odd numbers only
    }

    printf("\n\n Total numbers entered: %d", total_counter); //Show count of all numbers
    printf("\n Even numbers entered: %d", even_counter); //Show count of even numbers
    printf("\n Odd numbers entered: %d", odd_counter); //Show count of odd numbers

    even_p=(even_counter/total_counter)*100; //Calculate % of even numbers
    odd_p=(odd_counter/total_counter)*100; //Calculate % of odd numbers

    printf("\n\n Even numbers are %d %% of total number (%d out of %d)", even_p, even_counter, total_counter);
    printf("\n Odd numbers are %d %% of total number (%d out of %d)", odd_p, odd_counter, total_counter);
}
```

What works:

- It saves all entered numbers in one array, even and odd numbers in
  separate arrays.
- It counts how many numbers were entered, how many    are even and how
  many are odd.
- As soon as a non-numeric character is entered it goes to showing the
  result.

What doesn't work:

- The % calculation always says that it's 0%.
- The first number in the odd array is 0.

What I can't figure out:

- How to make it go to the results if nothing is entered? Tried
  `if (scanf("%d", &cinput) != "\n") break;`, but it just
  got stuck in the loop request another number.
- How to make the program exit if `exit` is entered?
- How to check if a whole number is entered?

**EDIT**

Counters initialized. scanf("%d", &cinput) changed to scanf("%d", &input). Changed even_p and odd_p to float (from int). Now the calculation is working fine and the first value in odd_array is good to.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int input, all [100], even[100], odd[100], even_counter, even_print, odd_counter, odd_print, total_counter, total_print;

    even_counter=0;
    even_print=0;
    odd_counter=0;
    odd_print=0;
    total_counter=0;
    total_print=0;
    for (;;)
    {

        printf("Enter a number: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &input) != 1) break;
        all[total_counter]=input; //Insert number in all numbers array

        if (input % 2 == 0)
        {
            even[even_counter]=input; //Insert number in even numbers array
            even_counter++;
            total_counter++;
        }
        if (input % 2 != 0)
        {
            odd[odd_counter]=input; //Insert number in odd numbers array
            odd_counter++;
            total_counter++;
        }
    }

    printf("\n You entered the following numbers: ");
    for (total_print=0; total_print<total_counter; total_print++)
    {
        printf("%d ", all[total_print]); //Show all entered numbers
    }
    printf("\n Even numbers are: ");
    for (even_print=0; even_print<even_counter; even_print++)
    {
        printf("%d ", even[even_print]); //Show even numbers only
    }
    printf("\n Odd numbers are: ");
    for (odd_print=0; odd_print<odd_counter; odd_print++)
    {
        printf("%d ", odd[odd_print]); //show odd numbers only
    }

    printf("\n\n Total numbers entered: %d", total_counter); //Show count of all numbers
    printf("\n Even numbers entered: %d", even_counter); //Show count of even numbers
    printf("\n Odd numbers entered: %d", odd_counter); //Show count of odd numbers

    float even_p=((float)(even_counter)/total_counter)*100; //Calculate % of even numbers
    float odd_p=((float)(odd_counter)/total_counter)*100; //Calculate % of odd numbers

    printf("\n\n Even numbers are %f %% of total number (%d out of %d)", even_p, even_counter, total_counter);
    printf("\n Odd numbers are %f %% of total number (%d out of %d)", odd_p, odd_counter, total_counter);
}
```

Now I just need the input to be checked if it's a whole number (display a message, but continue to ask for numbers), go to calculation if no value is entered, quit if `exit` is entered. And I forgot - the user should not be able to go to calculation if he enters less than 10 numbers. :(

Comment: You should scan a string and parse it according to your needs [helpful link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf)

Comment: 'if (scanf("%d", &cinput) != 1)' no.  cinput is a char, you read an int:(

Comment: You should initialize the counters to 0.

Comment: Counters initialized. `scanf("%d", &cinput)` changed to `scanf("%d", &input)`. Changed `even_p` and `odd_p` to `float` (from `int`). Now the calculation is working fine and the first value in `odd_array` is good to. Now any tips how to check if entered value is a whole number, break the loop if `\n` is entered and quit if `exit` is entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
even_p=(even_counter/total_counter)*100;
```

The above preforms **integer division**. You don't get an exact divisor, but the the integer immediately preceding it. Since `even_counter` is always less than `total_counter` you get zero.

A simple fix is to multiply first, and divide second:

```
even_p = even_counter * 100 / total_counter;
```

But your program has undefined behavior all around regardless. You don't initialize all of your variables. For instance, `odd_counter` isn't initialized, and yet you confidently read its value here:

```
    if (input % 2 != 0)
    {
        odd[odd_counter]=input; //Insert number in odd numbers array
        odd_counter++;
        total_counter++;
    }
```

---

The things you can't figure out can fill a post on their own. It's all about parsing. You need to read an entire line (say with `fgets`) and then try to parse it (for instance, with repeated applications of `sscanf`).

Comment: odd_counter is initialized at the beginning
Changed even_p and odd_p to float and it worked.

Comment: @KaralisArtūrs - No it isn't. It's declared, without any initialization.

Comment: Ok. So I changed
int input, all [100], even[100], odd[100], even_counter=0, even_print=0, odd_counter=0, odd_print=0, total_counter=0, total_print=0;

But even without initializing the % calculation worked when I changed it even_p and odd_p to float.

That leaves just the "Why is the first value in odd_array always a 0?"

Comment: @KaralisArtūrs - hold on. This is also a big no no `scanf("%d", &cinput)`. Conversion specifiers *must match* the types of the variables. Or the behavior of your program is undefined. Compile with all warnings enabled. And better yet, have the compiler treat them like errors, so you'd be forced to address them.

Comment: Originally it was `scanf("%d", &input)` but that would not work if I want the user to be able to enter "exit" to quit the program.

Comment: @KaralisArtūrs What makes you think `scanf("%d", &cinput);` would work? And `scanf("%d", &input);` would return 0 if you entered "exit".

Comment: I'm a complete beginner here. When I changed `&input` to `&cinput` I just forgot to change `"%d"` to `"%s"`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in the code.

First, your variables, especially `odd_counter` and so on are not initialised. Hence, an expression like `odd[odd_counter]=input` yields undefined behaviour (and actually you have a good chance that the program crashes). Note that in C local variables of integral type are NOT by default initialized, neither with `0` nor with any other value. So you need to write `int odd_counter=0, even_counter=0, ...` and so on. Otherwise your program might yield a correct output (as a correct output is one of thousands of possible outputs due to undefined behaviour), but it is for sure not guaranteed.

Second, `even_p=(even_counter/total_counter)*100` performs an integer division (nothing behind the comma), so `even_counter/total_counter` will always be `0` if `total_counter` is greater than `even_counter`. So you could write `even_p=((even_counter*100)/total_counter)`, or `(((float)even_counter)/total_counter)*100`. Decide if `even_p` should be `float` or `double` as well.

Third, you use `%d` (i.e. int) to scan into a variable of type `signed char`. Use `scanf("%hhd", &cinput)` instead; Format specifier `%d` together with length sub-specifier `hh` tells `scanf` to scan a numerical value into a signed char target (confer [printf/scanf reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)). Or: change type of variable `cinput` to `int`.

After fixing all these issues, the topic "Why is the first value in odd_array always a 0" should be solved as well.

Answer (score 0):

You declare

```
    char cinput;
```

and then use it in

```
    scanf("%d", &cinput)
```

That's bad, very bad... Format specifier `"%d"` expects a pointer to `int` as a corresponding parameter, not a pointer to `char`. And `int` is longer than `char` (typically 4 vs. 1 byte), so the input value gets stored *outside* the destination `cinput` variable.

What happens next is Undefined Behavior.