# C joining two functions

Tags: c, stdout

This is a standard bank account program. Allowing for deposit,withdrawal,and viewing funds. I am having trouble getting the program to enter the functions inside my switch statement which is based on their choice. Here is the output of this code.
[CodeOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vphvZ.jpg). I am not asking anyone to code for me, if you could maybe just point to where I went wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float getDeposit(float currentBalance);
float getWithdrawal(float currentBalance);
float displayBalance(float currentBalance);
char displayMenu();

int main()
{


    float currentBalance=200,newBalanceDep,newBalanceWith;
    char choice;
    choice = displayMenu();


        switch (choice)
    {

        case 'D': case 'd':
            newBalanceDep=getDeposit(currentBalance);
            break;
        case 'W': case 'w':
            newBalanceWith=getWithdrawal(currentBalance);
            break;
        case 'B': case 'b':
            displayBalance(currentBalance);
            break;
        case 'Q': case 'q':

            printf("Thank you!");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid choice.");
            break;

    }

    return 0;
}

char displayMenu()

{
    char choice;

    printf("Welcome to HFC Credit Union! \n"); 
    printf("Please select from the following menu: \n");
    printf("D: Make a deposit \n");
    printf("W: Make a withdrawal \n");
    printf("B: Check your account balance \n");
    printf("Q: To quit \n");

    scanf("\n%c",choice);

    return choice;

}

float getDeposit(float currentBalance)
{
    float depositAmount;
    float newBalanceDep;



    printf("Enter amount you would like to deposit: /n");
    scanf("%f",&depositAmount);

    if(depositAmount>0)
    {
        newBalanceDep=depositAmount+currentBalance;
    }

    return newBalanceDep;   
}

float getWithdrawal(float currentBalance)
{
    float withdrawalAmount;
    float newBalanceWith;

    printf("Enter amount you would like to withdrawal: /n");
    scanf("%f",&withdrawalAmount);

    if(withdrawalAmount>currentBalance)
    {
        printf("Insufficient Funds. Try again.");
        printf("Enter amount you would like to withdrawal: /n");
        scanf("%f",&withdrawalAmount);

    }
    else if(withdrawalAmount<=currentBalance)
    {
        newBalanceWith=withdrawalAmount+currentBalance;
    }

    return newBalanceWith;  
}

float displayBalance(float currentBalance)

{
    printf("Your current balance is %.2f",currentBalance);

}
```

Comment: Post the output as text instead of using an image.

Comment: Please provide useful informatin, a) not as picture b) not as external link. I.e. please edit your question to include the output as text. Also please explain what you do not like about the output. Reading [ask] and [mcve] might help.

Comment: That's the output I'm getting in the terminal

Comment: And what exactly is the error?

Comment: There is no error it just doesnt enter the functions i have posted in the switch statement

Comment: And you do not consider that an error?

Comment: "That's the output I'm getting in the terminal" No it isn't. There is only a link to an externally stored picture of an output.

Comment: thanks mr yunnosch it works now. just have to add a do while loop so the user can use it multiple times

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a string with scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `&choice` to `scanf`, not `choice`.

```
char choice; /*...*/; scanf("\n%c",choice); // --->    
//                                 v---- add  
char choice; /*...*/; scanf("\n%c",&choice);`
```

Passing `choice` is undefined behavior.

A good compiler should be giving you a warning.

Comment: I am using dev-c++ and i am getting no warning it just wont enter the functions in the switch statement based on users choice

Comment: @Jarute Use my suggestion and it will.

Comment: oh address operator gotcha i didnt read the whole thing i am in a scramble thanks alot it works