# I Can't figure out how to change a String and add more characters to the end

Tags: c, string, file, pointers, scanf

I'm trying to make a file pointer and I want the user to enter in the title and then have the program add .txt after the the title and here's one of the ways I tried to do it

```
int main()
{
    File * fpointer;
    char name;

    printf("Type name of program");
    scanf("%s.txt", &name);
    puts(&name);
}
```

Comment: you are scanning more  than 1 charcter, but char only holds one. Look at an array of char   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf

Comment: Note that `scanf("%s.txt", &name);` does not add `".txt"` to the input: it demands a match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scanf`'s approach will validate an input sequence to have `.txt` suffix. In addition, you do not have enough space for a string, because `name` can hold a single character.

If you want to force a suffix on an existing input, use `strcat` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME 40
int main() {
    File * fpointer;
    char name[MAX_NAME+5];
    printf("Type name of program: ");
    scanf("%40s", name);
    strcat(name, ".txt");
    puts(name);
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/vIxJO7)

Answer (score 1):

A `char` object can only hold a single character value.  To store a string, you need to use an *array* of `char`<sup>1</sup>:

```
#define MAX_NAME_LENGTH 20 // or whatever
...
char name[MAX_NAME_LENGTH+1]; // +1 for string terminator
```

Remember that in C, a *string* is a sequence of character values including a 0-valued terminator - for example, the string `"hello"` is represented as the character sequence `{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0 }`.  So your array needs to be large enough to handle the longest string you expect *plus* an extra element for the 0 terminator.  If you expect your largest string to be 20 characters long, then the array needs to be able to hold *at least* 21 characters.

For various historical reasons not worth going into right now, C I/O routines won't protect you if you try to write more characters to the array than it's sized to hold.  If `name` is sized to hold 20 characters plus the 0 terminator, and you read it as

```
scanf( "%s", name );
```

if someone enters 200 characters, then 180 characters will be written to the memory immediately following the `name` array, potentially leading to all kinds of mayhem.  Buffer overflows are a popular malware exploit, so it's a security issue as well.

To protect against that, you need to specify the max number of characters to read.  Unfortunately, `scanf` requires you to hardcode it as part of the conversion specifier, rather than providing it as a separate argument like `printf`.  You can't just use the macro like

```
scanf( "%MAX_NAME_LENs", name );
```

you either have to specify it as a numeric literal:

```
scanf( "%20s", name );
```

or use some preprocessor trickery to expand the macro and concatenate it with the format string:

```
#define EXPAND(x) #x
#define STR(x) EXPAND(x)
...
scanf( "%" STR(MAX_NAME_LEN) "s", name );
```

Ater preprocessing, that expands to

```
scanf( "%" "20" "s", name );
```

which is evaluated as

```
scanf( "%20s", name );
```

Or, you could go the easy route and use `fgets`:

```
fgets( name, sizeof name, stdin );
```

which is what I recommend.

---

1. Or `wchar_t` for "wide" strings, which you don't need to worry about right now.