# Trying to read information in a file (c programming)

Tags: c, file-io

I'm new to programming in  c and I've come across a problem with my file system. The aim of this program is for a user to **enter** a message and that message gets stored in a **text file**. After the users message gets **stored** in a text file, they have the choice to '**read**' a messaged their loved one has sent to them.

```
char SingleLine[150];
FILE * filePointer;
FILE * fpointer;
char mess[10];
char reply[100];

case 4:
    printf("enter a message: ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", mess);
    filePointer = fopen("gift.txt", "w");
    fprintf(filePointer, "%s \n", mess);
    printf("you said %s \n", mess);
    printf("they wrote something back?, would you like to read it?  yes or no? \n ");
    scanf("%s", &reply);    
    if ((toupper(reply[0]) == 'Y') && (toupper(reply[1]) == 'E') && (toupper(reply[2]) == 'S'))
    {
        printf("you said %s is that true???", &reply);
        printf("ok loading...\n");
        fpointer = fopen("luvtracey.txt", "r");
        while (!feof(fpointer))
            fgets(SingleLine, 150, fpointer);
            puts(SingleLine);
    }
    else if ((toupper(reply[0]) == 'N') && (toupper(reply[1]) == 'O'))
    {
        printf("wow ignorant \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("your not having it anymore");
    }
}
```

But when this code runs firstly, when a user **enters** a message with ***no spaces***, it'll get stored. But when you add spaces, the message would get **chopped** in half and the first bit would get stored. Secondly, when you type 'yes' (when you want to see what your loved one has sent) it crashes completely but i don't understand why. *Also* its not **retrieving** the information in the **'luvtracey.txt**' file which has words in it.

I accept feedback and i just want to say thank you to those in advance who help me solve these problems.

~Neamus

Comment: `printf("you said %s is that true???", &reply);` --> `printf("you said %s is that true???", reply);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a string with scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf)

Comment: You should always check what `fopen` (and other functions) returns to make sure your file has actually been opened or not and then deal with failures

Comment: There's  plenty of dupes, but in short, using the `%s` format specifier, 'fscanf' will read and store until  the first space in the input, leaving the remainings in the stream. So, if in input you have "Hello world. yes", you'll end up comparing "world." with {'Y', 'E', 'S'}… Try [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `if ((toupper(reply[0]) == 'Y') && (toupper(reply[1]) == 'E') ...`

You can convert the string to lowercase or uppercase and `strcmp`, rather than checking letters one by one.

> `while (!feof(fpointer))`
>   `fgets(SingleLine, 150, fpointer);`
>   `puts(SingleLine);`

Don't use [`feof`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). Instead check if `fgets` succeeds. Presumably you want to print each line in the file, so don't print the line after the loop finishes. You also need error checks to make sure the file was opened successfully. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[150];
    printf("enter a message: ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", buffer);
    printf("you said %s \n", buffer);

    FILE *fp = fopen("gift.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%s \n", buffer);
    fclose(fp);

    printf("yes or no? ");
    scanf("%s", buffer);
    for(int i = 0, len = strlen(buffer); i < len; i++)
        buffer[i] = (char)tolower(buffer[i]);
    if (strcmp(buffer, "yes") == 0)
    {
        fp = fopen("luvtracey.txt", "r");
        if(!fp)
        {
            printf("can't open...\n");
        }
        else
        {
            while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp))
                printf("%s", buffer);
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot rely on the operation of `fscanf` unless you check the return. You must handle 3-cases, `EOF`, success, and for *matching* or *input* failure. (`EOF` can be manually generated with `Ctrl+d` (Linux) or `Ctrl+z` (windoze), but see [CTRL+Z does not generate EOF in Windows 10](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/). This applies to every call to any of the `scanf` family of functions. Also `if (!fp)` simply handle the error and `return 1;` or `exit (EXIT_FAILURE);` there is no need to nest and `else`. `fscanf(stdin, "%149s", buffer);` protects bounds.