# Why do I get the segmentation dump error in this code?

Tags: c

I am new  to c and I am getting the segmentation dump error after first printf statement.
Please help me out with this error.

```
void main()
{
  char string[10]={};
  char key,used[10];
  int len=0;
  printf("Enter the string :");
  scanf("%s",&string);
  len = strlen(string);
  for (int i =0; i<len;++i)
  {
    int count=0;
    key =string[i];
    printf("%s",key);
    for (int j =0;j<len;++j)
    {
      if (string[j]==key)
      {
        count+=1;
      }
    }
    printf("%s %d",key,count);
  } 
}
```

Comment: `printf("%s",key);` should be `printf("%c",key);`. `%s` expects null terminated `char *` but you are passing `char`.  Develop good habit of considering compiler warnings.

Comment: Here char key is not array. Use key[size].

Comment: Besides taking heed to your compiler warnings (if yours didn't, it's settings aren't high enough and need to be raised), just take my word for it; being new to C, you simply cannot learn how to use a debugger soon enough. The sooner the better. You'll easily spend half your time using one over the course of a software engineering career.

Comment: `printf("%s %d",key,count)` is also wrong. `key` is `char`, not `char[]`.

Comment: `scanf("%s",&string);` should be `scanf("%s",string);` here's why :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment

`scanf("%s",&string);`  should be `scanf("%s",string);`

Use `correct format specifier`

`printf("%s",key);` should be `printf("%c",key);//<-----should be %c`
`printf("%s %d",key,count);` should be `printf("%c %d",key,count);//<-----should be %c`