# How to get data from fgets()

Tags: c, arrays, fgets

I have a data file with information like this:

```
    3 10.9
    1 2.1
    10 100.5
                               //This is a blank line
    10 200
```

The first is an integer and the second is a float data. It also needs to check whether a blank line exist. So I use a `float x[20]` array to contains it and use `fgets()` to get the value of each line. But how can I get back these values as `printf("%d%f",x[0],x[1]);` can't get back the value I wanted, it gives some strange values.[image: The output looks like this]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading a string with scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406935/reading-a-string-with-scanf)

Comment: Your description of your code is not sufficient to inform an answer to the question.  We need to see a [mre] demonstrating your problem to discuss any specifics of what may be wrong or how to fix it.

Comment: Don't post pictures of the code, post the code in text format.

Comment: Don't write `perror("Cannot open file!\n")`.  It is not helpful to omit the path, nor is it useful to include the newline.  Much better to write `perror("supermarket.dat")`.  Even better is to put the path in a variable and write `perror(path)`

Comment: Just post *all* the relevant code into one or more code blocks (i.e. indent it four spaces so it gets auto-formatted). It looks like I'm only seeing some of the code, that it's not well format (not styled well) and I have to read it in unusual ways in someone's personal style. Too much of a hassle. Moving on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
 fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, filehandle);
```

Then use

```
if (sscanf(buffer, "%d %f", &Intvar, &floatvar) == 2)
     // Data ready
```