# How do pointers in the structure work in the following code?

Tags: c, string, pointers, struct

I wanted to use pointer inside a struct to store 2 names the code works fine it stores and display the names as I want them to but I am confused about the role of the `&` operator in the `scanf` and `printf` statements when I remove the `&` operator from `printf` the names don't display. I don't know how its working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    struct name
    {
        char *p;
    }n1,n2; 
    
    printf("ENTER NAME1\n");
    scanf("%s",&n1.p);
    printf("\nENTER NAME2\n");
    scanf("%s",&n2.p);
    
    printf("ENTERED NAMES ARE %s , %s",&n1.p,&n2.p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pointers work like pointers anywhere, it doesn't matter if you have it as a separate local variable, argument, or part as a structure.

Comment: And for `scanf` with the `%s` format, it expects a pointer to the first element of an array of characters, of type `char *`. When you use the address-of operator you get a pointer *to the pointer*, and its type is `char **`. And same with `printf` and the `%s` format, it expects a pointer to the first element of an array of characters.

Comment: To be brutally honest, it seems like you have skipped way to much of your text-book, reading a really bad tutorial, or skipped to many classes. Start over, and if you don't have a book, *get one*, you can't learn a language (programming or spoken) by just guessing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5406935/1216776

Answer (score 0):

> the code works fine

The code has undefined behavior because in these calls

```
scanf("%s",&n1.p);
scanf("%s",&n2.p);
```

expressions &n1.p and &n2.p have the incorrect type `char **` and are overwritten.

You need to allocate memory where you are going to read strings.

Answer (score -1):

```
printf("ENTER NAME1\n");
scanf("%s",&n1.p);
printf("\nENTER NAME2\n");
scanf("%s",&n2.p);
```

Where do you want to store the strings with the names into?

Into the object of the pointer `p` inside of the respective structure itself?

This is invalid and illegal. Pointers are made to *point* anywhere, not to be assigned with a value of an object they do point to themselves.

Thus to answer your question:

> "*How do pointers in the structure work in the following code?*"

They don't work at all. Your code is a mess of [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

---

You need to allocate memory first, where `p` is pointing to, f.e. by using `malloc()`:

```
n1.p = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);   // Allocates memory for a string up to 19 characters.
if (!n1.p)
{
    fputs("Error at allocation!", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

n2.p = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);   // Allocates memory for a string up to 19 characters.
if (!n2.p)
{
    fputs("Error at allocation!", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

and then pass the argument to `scanf()` properly:

```
printf("ENTER NAME1\n");
scanf("%s", n1.p);

printf("\nENTER NAME2\n");
scanf("%s", n2.p);
```

(Note `n1.p` instead of `&n1.p`. Same goes for `n2.p`)

Or better:

```
printf("ENTER NAME1\n");
if (scanf("%s", n1.p) != 1)
{
    fputs("Error at input!", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}    

printf("\nENTER NAME2\n");
if (scanf("%s", n2.p) != 1)
{
    fputs("Error at input!", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

to ensure safety at input errors.

---

Furthermore the `%s` conversion specifier expects an argument of type `char *`, not pointer to `char *` (`char **`) as it is with `&n1.p` and `&n2.p`.

To provide an argument of wrong type invokes [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior), too.

Just use `n1.p` and `n2.p`.

---

Also this `printf()` call is wrong:

```
printf("ENTERED NAMES ARE %s , %s", &n1.p,&n2.p);
```

You need to omit the `&` too:

```
printf("ENTERED NAMES ARE %s , %s", n1.p, n2.p);
```

---

All in one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    struct name
    {
        char *p;
    } n1, n2; 

    n1.p = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);   // Allocates memory for a string up to 19 characters.
    if (!n1.p)
    {
        fputs("Error at allocation!", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    n2.p = malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);   // Allocates memory for a string up to 19 characters.
    if (!n2.p)
    {
        fputs("Error at allocation!", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    
    printf("ENTER NAME1\n");
    if (scanf("%s", n1.p) != 1)
    {
        fputs("Error at input!", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILUE;
    }    

    printf("ENTER NAME2\n");
    if (scanf("%s", n2.p) != 1)
    {
        fputs("Error at input!", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 
    
    printf("ENTERED NAMES ARE %s , %s", n1.p, n2.p);

    free(n1.p):
    free(n2.p);

    return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
ENTER NAME1
Peter
ENTER NAME2
Maria
ENTERED NAMES ARE Peter , Maria
```